# What font alternatives exist for Bremen Bd BT?

Tags: fonts, typography

The ideal alternative would have a “slated S” (as the Bremen one) but will not have the different stroke widths within the same letter (i.e. I'm looking for a more uniform stroke in the font like Helvetica).  Here is an example of the Bremen Bd BT Font:

[image: Bremen Bd BT]

I tried a couple of online services (Whatfontis.com, whatthefont.com, identifont.com) without finding anything suitable.

NOTE: The recommended font can be commercial.  I'm not a designer but I'm trying to help my team to choose a font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tambor by CastleType seems to be the closest match. It doesn't have the slanted S but shares similar characteristics as Bremen Bold while keeping a similar stroke throughout.

Tambor Medium
[image]

Tambor Bold
[image]

Comment: Closer to what I'm looking for.  Do you happen to know of a font that has a slanted S?  It doesn't have to resemble Bremen.  It just has to have a uniform stroke. I appreciate for your answer.

Comment: Only one I can think of that has a slanted S is [Plug Nickel NF](http://www.fontspace.com/nicks-fonts/plug-nickel-nf), but it does not have a uniform stroke. Whats the use of this font? You could possibly pull the S from Bremen or Plug Nickel and combine with tambor depending on the use.

Comment: It is used in a logo. The slanted S fits inside a shape with an angle. I'll share your suggestions with the team. Thanks again.